# InstallShield Limited Edition Dialog Appears Minimized

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-2012

I am using InstallShield Limited Edition (2012 Spring) along with Visual Studio 2012 to build setup / install programs for my software. I have three different setup projects. When executed, two of them have the annoying habit of showing  the Install Welcome dialog minimized. The first dialog, "Preparing To Install", appears normally - but when it closes, the end user has to look in the task bar for the minimized "Install Welcome" dialog box.

The third setup project does not do this, the InstallShield dialogs all remain visible until the installation has completed.

The difference between the projects is that the two that minimize themselves have a prerequisite specified  (.Net 4.0) while the one that remains visible throughout has no prerequisites. The behavior I'm describing happens when the prerequiste .Net 4.0 is already present, so no action is required.

I can't find any settings for the InstallShield Dialogs that would control this (or let me override it), and of course the Limited Edition limits what I can do. Other than the specified prerequisite, I can't find any other differences in the project settings.

Does anyone know how I can get all the InstallShield LE dialogs to appear visibly?

Answer (score 0):

This matches a known defect IOA-000059192 that was fixed in [InstallShield 2013 SP1](http://support.installshield.com/kb/view.asp?articleid=Q210472). It was triggered when including a prerequisite that has a condition testing msi.dll's version. If I'm reading our source history correctly, this fix should also be available in InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition, so you may just have to upgrade.